# Stimulsoft doesn't show correct pdf font in smart phone

Tags: asp.net, stimulsoft

I'm using 'stimulsoft' to generate PDF, after generating PDF file it doesn't display the correct font for Persian characters on smartphones, but correct on laptops.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?
I really appreciated any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use persian font in stimulsoft and use generated pdf in smart phone you should use the option of stimulsoft designer named export as a image for any component in your report.
As you can see in the below picture the export to image set to true for component.
[image]

after that in any smart phone you can use persian font without any problem.
I hope my answer is useful for you.

Comment: it worked for me and my problem solved @Mehrdad Noroozi

Comment: Searching for text which was written using the persian font, in the PDF, will probably no longer be possible?